# Bootstrap Modal doesn't fit screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I actually work on a project of a website wich is supposed to fit on IOS and Android. Then, there's my problem:

In IOS/Android resolution: I got a button that opens a modal, inside a window that contains a table wich is larger than the resolution. This table goes out from the page, but that's normal, and that's what i want. That button, when i click, successfully opens the modal, but this modal doesn't fit on the visible screen: it fit on the whole page and so, it's not fully visible.

What I want would be the modal to fit the screen size. And not being masked on the part of the window we have to scroll to view.
That should be possible and realistic, but i tried a lot without any success.

I send u some screenshots to make you see my problem more clearly:

1/ The window with the button: "Launch Demo Modal"
[first exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWP09.png)

2/ The window when i click the button and the modal appears
[second exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m14cm.png)

My problem is located on the second picture. I wish the modal to fit the screen.

The code:

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I truelly thank you for any answers,

Comment: ...and the CSS is basic Bootstrap or what?

Comment: yes it is, i downloaded it on getbootstrap.com

Comment: @shqnks re-create your problem in fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/, it's not hard to create a fiddle, just open the page you have problem, take view source, copy rendered HTML relevant code, put it in fiddle, save it and past the link here, it will get you better help and answers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hudwu9pf/

In this link, it works. I just copyed my HTML and CSS code, with the same includes that exists inside my <head>. I'm truelly lost: in my project, it's the same as before. The modal dont fit the screen, but the page.

Comment: PS: It works on Mozilla, but not in Google Chrome.... i'm gonna cry very hard. I forgot to say that i use the F12 button to see the Iphone5 view for my tests. And is this case it dont work, wich is very important.

Comment: tested your fiddle in chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 and modal is working fine.

Comment: Yep it works on my chrome too, but it dont work on my project when i try Iphone5 view!
If you want to clearly see my problem:
Go in the fiddle, press F12, select iphone5 mode, press F5, resize the border on the right to make the table going out of the screen, and you'll see that the modal will fit to the table and not the avable screen.

Comment: http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/iphonemodal.html can you see the problem here, and if yes lemme know when switching to iphone5, what's the width of screen you think modal start cutting and it shouldn't.

Comment: On you're version of the project, the resizing doesn't happens and then the text is very small what makes the table fit on screen. Look like not responsive. But the problem happens when you set the width under approximatively 250px.

Comment: agree with you that at screen width 250px modal cut from right but iPhone 5 and 5s width is 320px min but yes in bootstrap responsive media queries start from 480px so i think you have to write couple of media queries according to iPhone 5 screen size

Comment: try this media query, `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {.modal-dialog {margin: 10px;width: inherit;}}`

Comment: i copyied your media queries and the issue is still the same. But thanks to look at my problem ^^

Comment: still didn't find any solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this media query.

```
 @media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
  .modal-xs { width: @modal-sm; }
 }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! where do i need to write this code?

Comment: edit: I copyied it between <style > balises and it still doesn't work :/